# bash: -exec in find command and &

Tags: bash, find

I want to run:

```
./my_script.py a_file &
```

... on all files in the current folder that end with `.my_format`, so I do:

```
find . -type f -name "*.my_format" -exec ./my_script {} & \;
```

but it doesn't work. How should I include `&` in the `-exec` parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the find command's "exec" feature start a program in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853451/can-the-find-commands-exec-feature-start-a-program-in-the-background)

Comment: is there a point in pointing it out one year later?

Comment: I got to this question when facing this very problem, and it's definitively not a bad question. At this point, mentioning it's a duplicate is a way of notifying future readers other answers are available, that's all.

Comment: Finally, only [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853537/2518705) to similar question helped me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.my_format" -exec sh -c './my_script {} &' \;
```

The mostly likely reason your attempt didn't work is because find executes the command using one of the `exec(3)` family of standard c library calls which don't understand job control - the `&` symbol. The shell does understand the "run this command in the background" hence the `-exec sh ...` invocation

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. So `sh` is the basic shell on all linux machines, right?

Comment: Recent linux distros symlinks /bin/sh to a shell that is posix-sh compliant.

Comment: If we spawn a new shell for each execution why would we also need to 
 add the executed command in the background?

Comment: The shell is executed one after another. Putting it in the background have a side effect of the shell script to be run in parallel (as many as the CPU can handle at one time).

Comment: This works, but handle with care. If there are a lot of files in the tree you're recursing, you're system will probably lock up.

Answer (score 5):

Try this find command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.my_format" -exec bash -c './my_script "$1" &' - '{}' \;
```