# How to use the find -exec command to create background processes and wait for them?

Tags: bash, find, exec, background-process

I have a main bash script which is supposed to start another bash script with different inputs as background processes and then wait for it. For this I'm using `find dir_path -exec bash -c '. another_batchscript.sh {} $0' ${second_input} \;` (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146676/bash-exec-in-find-command-and)), and then I have a `wait` command in my main script. The problem is that this script is almost immediately finished.

I thought about it and realized that when I execute `sleep 10 &` from the command line, I can find the job with executing the `jobs` command. But when I execute `bash -c 'sleep 10 &'` then `jobs` won't find it. This is probably why the wait command doesn't block in my main bash script.

Why does this happen and how do I have to change my command in the main batch script to solve my problem?

Comment: Your question seems kind of stuck in the minutiae of background tasks and waiting. Maybe take a step back and say what you are actually trying to do overall.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean. I'm interested in a general way to start background processes where each of these processes executes a bash script with different input each, and then I want to wait for them to finish. At the moment I'm working on a special case where it would be useful to have this, but I'm not sure if it would help to talk about the exact content of these scripts. The problem is that my main script doesn't wait for the processes it started with above described find -exec command and this should be independent of the content of the bash scripts, shouldnt it?

Comment: And my main script is as described above: at first the find -exec command and then a wait. But it finished almost immediately, because I suspect that the wait command doesn't work here. See above where I argued with the jobs command that processes started with this find -exec command in this particular way seem not to be recognized as child processes

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to answer you when you are not very forthcoming about what you are trying to do, but from what you have said, I don't think `find ... -exec` with a `wait` is the correct approach.

I can only make some vague suggestions as follows:

- run `find` and put the resulting filenames into a `bash` array, or a file, then loop over that array or file running whatever you want to do in the background and add a `wait` at the end
- run `find` and pipe the filenames into **GNU Parallel** and run the jobs in parallel like that with lots of control over progress reporting, CPU-usage and parameter substitution

  `find ... -print0 | parallel -0 ...`